# How to used scheduler in informix

Tags: scheduler, informix, autorun

If I have a stored procedure and need to be run automatically for example every 5 minutes, so how can I use the built in scheduler function in Informix 12.10 ?
Can someone give me advice on what I need to do?
Thanks

Comment: Did you try something? Can we see? code/logic?

Answer (score 2):

Essentially what you need to do is add a row into the ph_task table of the sysadmin database. Take a look at the topic "Creating a task" in the section describing the scheduler in the Administrator's Guide https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.admin.doc/ids_admin_1122.htm.

There is also further information describing the columns of the ph_task table at https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.adref.doc/ids_adr_0272.htm